# connecting to database using RMySQL, R and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, r, database-connection

I am trying to connect to my database from R.  When I start the server from the shell (using unix), i have to pass the --ssl-ca=myfile.  How do I pass this flag using the dbConnect function? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. Create a file in some directory and in that file write the following:

```
[client]
password=yourpass
username=yourusername
...
ssl-ca=yourcertspath
```

Then pass the file name to the default.file param of `dbConnect`