# Trouble connecting to Amazon RDS using RMySQL using SSL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Following up on a [previous answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482945/connecting-to-database-using-rmysql-r-and-mysql), I'm using RMySQL to connect to my Amazon RDS instance.  I can connect without SSL, but would prefer to connect over SSL using the provided certificate for my EC2 instance. This method seems to work fine using Sequel Pro.

However, when attempting the same connection in R using the RMySQL package, I get the following error:

```r
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), default.file='~/Desktop/mysql.cfg')
Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
)
```

In addition to my regular authentication parameters, the `mysql.cfg` file contains the path to my .pem file provided by Amazon, (e.g., ssl-ca='~/.ssh/file.pem'). Am I missing an additional parameter?

Comment: It appears that my EC2 file is actually a key.  I then tried changing `ssl-ca` to `ssl-key` but still received this error: `SSL error: Unable to get certificate from '/Users/me/.ssh/MacbookAir.pem'
Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: SSL connection error: Unable to get certificate
)`

Comment: Can you try again with the new version of RMySQL?

Comment: Try using absolute paths as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709581/ssl-connection-error-when-connecting-to-rds-mysql-from-django